# Prime number that are recursively made up of other prime number -- what is this called

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I've noticed that some prime number are composed entirely of other prime numbers

for example -- some have parents on the left hand side (all the numbers below are prime):

```
59393339
5939333
593933
59393
5939
59
5
```

Others for example -- some have parents on the right hand side (all the numbers below are prime):

```
633396997
 33396997
  3396997
   396997
    96997
     6997
      997
       97
        7
```

Others have parents on both side, for example:

```
739397 on the right hand side
 39397
  9397
   397
    97
     7

739397 on the left hand side
73939
7393
739
73
7
```

I'd like to know what these type of Prime numbers are called?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're called [truncatable primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncatable_prime).

For a list of them on OEIS, see [A024785](https://oeis.org/A024785), [A020994](https://oeis.org/A020994), [A055521](https://oeis.org/A055521)